# PHP and Mysql with INNER JOIN query - only seeing headers, no data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "konkal"); 
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"
            SELECT * 
              FROM tb_hitung 
              JOIN tb_makanan 
                ON tb_hitung.id = tb_makanan.id 
             WHERE ket_waktu = 'pagi' 
            ");
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
?>
            <tr>
                <th>Gambar Makanan</th>
                <th>Nama Makanan</th>
                <th>Jenis Makanan</th>
                <th>Waktu Makan</th>
                <th>Jumlah Kalori</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $row['gambar'] ?>" width="100"></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["nama"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["kategori"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["ket_waktu"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["kkal"]," kkal" ?></td>
            </tr>
```

**Table `tb_hitung`:**

```
id  kkal        ket_waktu
12  360 kkal    pagi
2   810 kkal    malam
24  108 kkal    siang
9   286 kkal    pagi
```

**Table `tb_makanan`:**

```
id  name    kategori    keterangan  gambar
2   Ampela  Lauk        270         Amepela.jpg
3   Usus    Lauk        473         Usus
4   Bebek   Lauk        300         Bebek
```

I expect the output to display results where the query filters ket_waktu = 'pagi'.  I am only seeing the first row of table (the headers).

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the `while` line is ending the loop. You need to put the table rows inside the loop.

Comment: Also, the table headings should not be inside the loop, just the data rows.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, it seems really odd that the PRIMARY KEY id of one table should correspond to the PRIMRY KEY id of another table.

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1**

Join point `tb_hitung.id = tb_makanan.id` only creates one "match".
For example: tb_hitung id **12** should match to tb_makanan id **12**.  but tb_makanan has ZERO ROWS with id **12** (no match).

*There is a single match...it is on `hitung 2` and `makanan 2`...but the **where clause** filters to hitung of "pagi".  So given this data, the query will have ZERO ROWS*.

**PART 2**

As @barmar mentions...the semicolon ends your `while` loop without ever looping *and* the header row should not be within what appears to be your loop.  I'll clarify all this chit-chat with one example of an appropriate loop for this purpose:

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*******", "", "*******"); 

  // keep your query in a variable for quick debugging
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_hitung JOIN tb_makanan  ON tb_hitung.id = tb_makanan.id";

  // i removed the WHERE clause since it was filtering all rows

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  // print your header row OUTSIDE the loop
  ?>

    <tr><th>Gambar</th><th>Nama</th><th>Jenis</th><th>Waktu</th><th>Jumlah</th></tr>

  <?php

  // now do the loop of the data...
  // WHILE should open with an OPENING BRACKET (not end with a semicolon)
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>

       <tr>
         <td><img src="<?php echo $row['gambar'] ?>" width="100"></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["nama"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["kategori"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["ket_waktu"] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["kkal"]," kkal" ?></td>
       </tr>

    <?php
  // now we must END THE WHILE LOOP
  }
```